# stargazer package producing empty summary table

Tags: r, statistics, stargazer

i am having an issue using the stargazer package. i have downloaded the newest version of r (4.1.3) for mac but when I try to get a summary statistic table with the stargazer package the table comes up empty.here is what I have written in my script. i have downloaded stargazer and all other necessary packages I think.

```
stargazer(econ.dta[c("responses", "price", "offers", "bestoffer", "meanoffer", "name", "polite", "black", "tattoo", "white")] , type = "text",       
          summary.stat = c("mean", "sd", "median", "min", "max"))
```

data

```
structure(list(ad = structure(c(55, 59, 60, 65, 66, 67), label = "Ad ID", format.stata = "%8.0g"), responses = structure(c(0, 1, 2, 0, 5, 2), label = "Number of responses", format.stata = "%9.0g"), offers = structure(c(0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1), label = "Number of offers", format.stata = "%9.0g"), bestoffer = structure(c(NA, 95, NA, NA, 90, 75), label = "Best offer", format.stata = "%9.0g"), meanoffer = structure(c(NA, 95, NA, NA, 82.5, 75), label = "Mean offer", format.stata = "%9.0g"),
               name = structure(c(NA, 1, 1, NA, 0.200000002980232, 0), label = "Incl.\\ name", format.stata = "%8.0g"), polite = structure(c(NA, 1, 1, NA, 0.600000023841858, 0), label = "Polite", format.stata = "%8.0g"), price = structure(c(130, 110, 90, 110, 90, 110), label = "Asking price", format.stata = "%8.0g"), texttype = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), label = "Text series", format.stata = "%9.0g", labels = c(A = 0, B = 1, C = 2), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double")), 
               black = structure(c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1), label = "Black", format.stata = "%9.0g", labels = c(Other = 0, Black = 1), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double" )), tattoo = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), label = "Tattoo", format.stata = "%9.0g", labels = c(Other = 0, Tattoo = 1), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double" )), white = structure(c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0), label = "White", format.stata = "%9.0g", labels = c(Other = 0, White = 1), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double"))), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame" ))
```

Comment: please someone help. do i need to add data frame of some kind?

Comment: Please provide the output of `dput(econ.dta)` so that we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Do you mean the data I’m using or the result on my r when I run the above line?

Comment: The data you are using (`econ.dta`).

Comment: It won’t allow me to add a picture here or to copy the link form the data I’m using. Is there a way around this

Comment: Yes, and you should provide a picture, but copy and paste the output of that function. If there's too much data, use `dput(head(econ.dta))`.

Comment: structure(list(ad = structure(c(55, 59, 60, 65, 66, 67), label = "Ad ID", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    responses = structure(c(0, 1, 2, 0, 5, 2), label = "Number of responses", format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
    offers = structure(c(0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1), label = "Number of offers", format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
    bestoffer = structure(c(NA, 95, NA, NA, 90, 75), label = "Best offer", format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
    meanoffer = structure(c(NA, 95, NA, NA, 82.5, 75), label = "Mean offer", format.stata = "%9.0g"),

Comment: name = structure(c(NA, 1, 1, NA, 0.200000002980232, 0), label = "Incl.\\ name", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    polite = structure(c(NA, 1, 1, NA, 0.600000023841858, 0), label = "Polite", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    price = structure(c(130, 110, 90, 110, 90, 110), label = "Asking price", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    texttype = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), label = "Text series", format.stata = "%9.0g", labels = c(A = 0, 
    B = 1, C = 2), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr",

Comment: "double")), black = structure(c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1), label = "Black", format.stata = "%9.0g", labels = c(Other = 0, 
    Black = 1), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double"
    )), tattoo = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), label = "Tattoo", format.stata = "%9.0g", labels = c(Other = 0, 
    Tattoo = 1), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double"
    )), white = structure(c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0), label = "White", format.stata = "%9.0g", labels = c(Other = 0, 
    White = 1), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double"

Comment: ))), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), notes = c("scrapes-raw.dta created 6 Apr 2013 15:54 from scrapes.dat using import.do", 
"scrapes.dta created 6 Apr 2013 15:54 from scrapes-raw.dta using import.do", 
"states.dta created 6 Apr 2013 15:54 from states.csv using import.do", 
"markets.dta created 6 Apr 2013 15:54 from markets.csv using import.do", 
"advertisements.dta created 6 Apr 2013 15:54 from advertisements.csv using import.do",

Comment: i ran the dput(head(econ.dta)) like you suggested and copied and pasted the results for you here

Comment: This should have been provided as an edit to the question, not as comments.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues going on. The first is that some of the variables are actually of class "haven-labelled" which doesn't play nicely, so we need to "zap" the labels:

```
econ.dta <- haven::zap_labels(econ.dta)
```

The second is that it seems that the stargazer package doesn't work well with tibbles, so it needs to be converted as a data frame:

```
stargazer(as.data.frame(econ.dta[c("responses", "price", "offers", "bestoffer", "meanoffer", "name", "polite", "black", "tattoo", "white")]), 
          type = "text",       
          summary.stat = c("mean", "sd", "median", "min", "max"))


===============================================
Statistic  Mean   St. Dev. Median  Min    Max  
-----------------------------------------------
responses  1.667   1.862    1.5     0      5   
price     106.667  15.055   110     90    130  
offers     0.667   0.816    0.5     0      2   
bestoffer 86.667   10.408    90     75     95  
meanoffer 84.167   10.104  82.500 75.000 95.000
name       0.550   0.526   0.600  0.000  1.000 
polite     0.650   0.473   0.800  0.000  1.000 
black      0.500   0.548    0.5     0      1   
tattoo     0.000   0.000     0      0      0   
white      0.500   0.548    0.5     0      1   
-----------------------------------------------
```